# Querying External tables with built-in function in Azure Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I see performance issue in following query while executing on external table vs native database table with built-in function in Azure SQL database. Example

```sql
select top  1000000 vs.*
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by vs.context_id order by vs.value) 
from Tbl_sign vs
JOIN Tbl_cli ce 
ON  ce.[Clinical Encounter ID] = vs.[Clinical Encounter ID]
and ce.[CONTEXT_ID] = vs.[CONTEXT_ID]
```

Execution time for native database table - 1 mins and 10 secs
Execution time for non-native database external table - 4 mins and 5 secs

If anyone has Azure SQL database access, pls check query performance against table in native DB vs exernal table non-native DB with built in function.

ex.

- Tbl_sign and Tbl_cli table in native DB called ABC
- Tbl_sign and Tbl_cli external table in non-native DB called DEF having external data source = ABC

Any thoughts on why performance is different?

Comment: For performance issues we need to see the table *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable otherwise

Comment: Query plan is particularly important, because even a specific table X with indexes Y can result in different query plans based on the underlying data. So, while it is _sometimes_ possible to see enough in table+indexes, other times it's necessary to also see the query plan.

Comment: I agree with both of you. It is just simple question executing same query in Azure SQL
1. against table in native database called A
2. against external table in non-native database called B

Comment: How can anyone provide suggestions to improve performance? If the query is the same in both environments, then there is something environment-specific about why the performance is different. Size of data, hardware differences, differences in indexes, who knows. But the only thing provided so far is the query. I don’t know how anyone will be able to help without additional information.

Comment: Well if you agree then why don't you share the query plans via the above link? Help us to help you.